# Javascript : access subobject in array

Tags: javascript

i'm wondering how can i access subobject is this example:

```
let obj = {
   helloworld:'hello',
   helloworldobj:{
     hello:'hello',
     world: 'world',
   }
}

console.log({ ...obj , ['helloworld']: 'helloworld' }); --> this is fine
console.log({ ...obj , ['helloworldobj'['hello']]: 'hello2' }); -->
```

This is wrong but wondering here how can i access hello or world ?

expected output :

```
let obj = {
   helloworld:'helloworld',
   helloworldobj:{
     hello:'hello2',
     world: 'world',
   }
}
```

Comment: `['helloworldobj'['hello']]:` - What is this supposed to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: Whats the expected output of the second `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work like this:

```js
let obj = {
   helloworld:'hello',
   helloworldobj:{
     hello:'hello',
     world: 'world'
   }
}

console.log({
    ...obj, 
    helloworldobj : {
        ...obj.helloworldobj,
        hello : 'hello2'
    }
})

// alternatively if you want to use variables to access properties

prop1 = 'helloworldobj'
prop2 = 'hello'

console.log({
    ...obj, 
    [prop1] : {
        ...obj[prop1],
        [prop2] : 'hello2'
    }
})
```

Comment: `['helloworldobj']: ...` is the exact same as `'helloworldobj': ...`

Comment: Got it, this is working fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(obj['helloworldobj']['hello']);
```

or

```
console.log(...obj['helloworldobj']['hello']);
```